# NOTSTT error: expecting a statement in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have this simple test code(test.v) to generate an compile error.

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

`define START 'h10000000;
`define WIDTH 800
`define HEIGHT 600

module test;
integer ifm_addr;
integer ifm_idx;

initial begin
    ifm_idx = 0;
    ifm_addr = `START + ifm_idx*4*`HEIGHT*`WIDTH;
end

initial begin
#1000;
$finish;
end

endmodule
```

when I run `ncvlog test.v`, I get this error and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
ncvlog: 12.20-s008: (c) Copyright 1995-2013 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
    ifm_addr = `START + ifm_idx*4*`HEIGHT*`WIDTH;
                      |
ncvlog: *E,NOTSTT (test.v,11|19): expecting a statement [9(IEEE)].
    ifm_addr = `START + ifm_idx*4*`HEIGHT*`WIDTH;
                               |
ncvlog: *E,MISEXX (test.v,11|28): expecting an '=' or '<=' sign in an assignment [9.2(IEEE)].
```

Please help!

EDIT : The error was because of the `;` at the end of `define START 'h10000000`. It makes the `+` appear after a statement in the `initial` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined `ifm_idx`.

```
module test;
  integer ifm_addr;
  integer ifm_idx;


  initial begin
    ifm_addr = `START + ifm_idx*4*`HEIGHT*`WIDTH;
  end
```

Comment: try removing the `'h` from the define. It worked fine on eda playground for me once ifm_idx was defined.

Comment: Oh, the error was because of `;` at the end of `define START `h10000000.

Comment: glad you solved it. Verilog errors for missing/extra `;` are very cryptic.